# GPIO events fire from unrelated pins

Tags: gpio, rpi.gpio

I'm using the RPi.GPIO library to control a the GPIO pins on my RPi, I have a 12 bit ADC which is bit-banged to get the data in a similar manner to [this tutorial on adafruit](http://learn.adafruit.com/reading-a-analog-in-and-controlling-audio-volume-with-the-raspberry-pi/).  This has been working well as a temperature logging circuit from a couple of TMP37 analogue thermometers.

I am now wanting to expand the use to monitor a flashing LED on my electricity meter and have constructed a photo-transistor circuit which works well as a receiver. When combining these two projects with the python code

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import pi_breakout
import time

#print GPIO.VERSION
PHOTOIN=14 # GPIO pin connected to Photo sensor

def elecpulsecallback(ch_num):
    print "pulse on ch {:d}".format(ch_num)

GPIO.setup(17, GPIO.OUT) # CPICLK
GPIO.setup(11, GPIO.OUT) #
GPIO.setup(9, GPIO.OUT) #
GPIO.setup(10, GPIO.IN) # SPIMISO
GPIO.setup(PHOTOIN, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.remove_event_detect(PHOTOIN)
GPIO.add_event_detect(PHOTOIN, GPIO.RISING, callback=elecpulsecallback, bouncetime=200)
while True:
    time.sleep(0.2)
    n=pi_breakout.readadc(1, 17,9,10,11) # bit bang code in separate file
    print n
```

I see the `elecpulsecallback` callback code fired every time I make a call to the ADC.  It seems to happen whichever pin I have the `PHOTOIN` assigned to even though the callback argument always indicates that it is `PHOTOIN` that is rising.  If I shorten the `bouncetime` I can get multiple events.

Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT: I seem to have solved the problem.  On closer inspection of the pin voltages, GPIO was at ~1.4V when the `pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP` or `pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_OFF`.  Snipping the 3.3V zenner I had on the input for protection seems to have solved the problem.

Comment: Could be a wiring problem, generation noise on GPIO 14. Could you post a photo of your wiring?

Comment: I'm using a breakout board based on this http://www.thebox.myzen.co.uk/Raspberry/Breakout.html I'll take a photo over the weekend.  It's not specific to GPIO14. It seems to fire whichever pin I set PHOTOIN to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by snipping the 3.3V zenner I had on the input for protection

Comment: care to explain what you mean by 'snipping'? As a non-native English speaker I don't get what you did :)

Comment: Snipping means to cut thought, or to remove